# IOS Live streaming

Tags: nsurlprotocol, gcdwebserver

Problem: 
I need to download mp4 video from media server and simultaneously feed the localhost httpserver (GCDWebServer) to enable video streaming.

What have i tried so far: 
I am able to download a video file from media server and then provide the localhost url for streaming the video.

But this takes a lot of time in downloading. So i wanted to know if there is a way i can segment the video on the fly and keep updating the m3u8 file as and when my next segment is ready.

Ok, Why downloading? Basically i need to deal with a custom encrypted video file. So i need to download, then decrypt the stream and then feed to my local httpserver.

I hope i'm clear in the requirements.

Comment: cocoahttpserver could be used to download and relay the content